# How can I make some external code run before a Windows service starts

Tags: windows-services, autostart

This probably sounds crazy, but it's a real problem: I have an ISV-provided Windows service that I cannot change. There's a bug in the service where it doesn't "clean up" some data that it should upon startup.

As a workaround, until the vendor can fix the bug, I would like to cause another process or script to always run just before this problem service starts.

For example: I could create a second "monitor" service that is tied to the problem service with a service dependency. The second service would perform this workaround/cleanup before the problem service is allowed to start. But that seems like a sledgehammer of a solution to a simple problem. Anyone else have ideas for a simpler solution?

The workaround code is trivial and could live, for example, in a PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new [service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) that does what you need, then force a [dependency](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/400/kb400960.html) on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out our [Service Protector application](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceProtector/) which can run a pre-startup script before starting another service. It too may be overkill, but sometimes it is better to purchase a targeted utility rather than investing your programming time in a one-off/throw-away solution.

In any case, your solution of writing another service and enforce a dependency should do the trick, provided that **your new service does not declare itself as "Started" until after it has completed its cleanup work**. If not, Windows may start your real service too soon.

Good luck.